# Angular get tag content inside a specific ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-selectors

I have an HTML template as follows:

```
<div id="expenses">
    <submenu>
    </submenu>
</div>

<div id="revenues">
    <submenu>
    </submenu>
</div>
```

I need to hold the submenu content in seperate variables. The following code works in angular:

```
var expenses = angular.element('#expenses')
```

However, I need to get one step further and get the submenu content in the variable. Something like:

```
var expenses = angular.element('#expenses>submenu')
```

But CSS selectors don't work in that function. How can I get the submenu contents?

Comment: `document.querySelector('#expenses > submenu')` ?

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using jQuery alongside Angular.  However, typically this is an indication you don't really "get" the Angular way. See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Thanks @OmriAharon for the answer!

Comment: @FarukYazıcı That solves it for you? Shall I put it as an answer?

Comment: @OmriAharon yes I would accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.querySelector('#expenses > submenu');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use find() function to get child elements.

```
    element.find("submenu")
```

Comment: The ID is on the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

may be:

```
var expenses = angular.element('#expenses').children()
```